# Select dynamic value id drop down web browser c#

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I am trying to select a size on a pair of clothing through the `WebBrowser` in C#.

The drop down has the HTML of:

```
<select id="size" name="size"><option value="32620">30</option>
<option value="32621">32</option>
<option value="32622">34</option>
<option value="32623">36</option>
</select>
```

As you can see 32,34,36 are the sizes and they correspond to a value, however these values change per item even for the same size.

To select size 32 I am using:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("size").SetAttribute("value", "32621");
```

This only works for a specific item, how can I set the size just by using the string `"32"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `InnerText` of the option tags and check for the value of the tag with an `InnerText` of "32".
Something along those lines should do the trick:

```
HtmlElementCollection elCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("option");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elCol)
{
     if(el.InnerText == "32")
     {
          String val = el.GetAttribute("value");
          webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("size").SetAttribute("value", val);
          break;
     }
}
```